# "EVM becomes a sidechain" - Solidity

Tags: solidity, wasm, ewasm

I recently came across a comment from Vitalik Buterin on reddit where he said that the EVM will eventually either become a sidechain or a contract written in EWASM. The comment can be found [here](https://old.reddit.com/r/ethereum/comments/8q05vn/about_the_sudden_change_in_casper_and_sharding/e0gufyy/)

> even the EVM itself will eventually become either a sidechain or a contract written in E-WASM as the rest of the chain implements EWASM

That was quite a surprise to me. Does that mean that we won't be able to write contracts with Solidity in the future and basically have to switch to Rust or C++? Then why is there even work on [Py-EVM](https://github.com/ethereum/py-evm) if it is going to be deprecated?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually the solidity compiler can output ewasm already. So you do not have to use another language if you do not want.

But I do not think the change is imminent. It will take some time until changes arrive to mainnet.